# Ошибка с Google sheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Делаю базу данных из google таблиц на питоне.

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

scope = [
    'https://googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
]

creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('creds.json', scopes=scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('user')
```

Здесь выдаёт ошибку sheet, а именно:

> No access token in response.

хотя я предоставил доступ редактора.

Comment: Я так понимаю Google sheet хочет токен увидеть

Comment: Вы всё верно понимаете